# Java code that works like this php code

Tags: java, php, file

```
$keys = file($KeysFile);
foreach($keys as $aKeys){
    $Keys = explode(' ', $aKeys);
    $Info[] = array($Keys[0], trim($Keys[1]));
}
```

I have a text file in the format

```
id securitykey

id securitykey

id securitykey

id securitykey
```

No blank space in between.. there is one set of id and security key on each line.. I need to be able to split the id and security key so I can have each in a variable of its own, and then put the id and security key in another array so I could call it like this

```
int i = 0;

Info[i][0]
```

and that would output the id and

```
int i = 0;

Info[i][1]
```

would output the securitykey..

I just need to be pointed in the right direction, Im pretty new to java, and coming from php I want to convert alot of my projects made in php to java applications with GUIs

Comment: Can you please rewrite this question with real code you are using and what you are trying to do.  This isn't really a great question and therefore cannot receive a great answer.

Comment: The right direction would be a book on learning Java. Or at the very least going through the tutorials available on Oracle's site - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all read data line by line : [Read file line by line](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml)

Then you need to `split` (in php `explode`) the line (string) : [Split a string using String.split()](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html)

And after that you can use it as you need it.